# Default routing is not working [Angular4]

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-router

I tired anything but it's happen only this project. I used the same routing code but default routing is not working. Do I need to fixed in code or I need to fix somewhere else?

This code is in *app.moules.ts*:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }, {
        path: '',
        component: AdminLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'main',
                component: MainComponent,
                data: {
                    breadcrumb: 'Main',
                    status: true
                }
            }, {
                path: 'userterminal',
                loadChildren: './userterminal/userterminal.module.ts#UserTerminalModule'
            }, {
                path: 'userslogin',
                loadChildren: './user-login/userlogin.module.ts#UserloginModule'
            }, {
                path: 'cameraconfig',
                loadChildren: './camera-config/camera- 
                config.module.ts#CameraConfigModule'
            }
        ]
    }, {
        path: '',
        component: AuthLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'authentication',
                loadChildren: './authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule'
            }, {
                path: 'error',
                loadChildren: './error/error.module#ErrorModule'
            }, {
                path: 'login',
                component: LoginComponent,
            }, {
                path: 'cameraLogin',
                component: CamLoginComponent
            }
        ]
    }, {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: 'error/404'
    }
];
```

Comment: are you using @angular/cli?

Comment: what do you exactly mean by default routing ? you mean routing the user to the login page or to the error/404 page ?

Comment: @NadhirFalta login page

Comment: @pixelbits Yes, version 1.3.1

Comment: I think you have a problem with your routes as well. Is there any reason why you want to *always* navigate the user to the login page when the path is empty?

You also have many empty routes on the same level.

Comment: @Nico I think when I put children. It need to put empty path. If I not put .It will get error: Invalid configuration of route '': routes must have either a path or a matcher specified

Comment: You do not have to put `loadChildren` inside of `children`
Take a look at https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-declarative-lazy-loading-7071d1f203ee It's outdated but still very relevant.

You have some declarative errors with your routes.

For example: You can do
`{
  path: 'authentication',
  loadChildren: './authentication/authentication.module#AuthenticationModule'
}`
Instead this way you are not referencing the `AuthLayoutComponent` outside of the lazy loaded bundled and inside you can define an empty route that will load like
{ path: ' ', component: AuthLayoutComponent }

Comment: @Nico I already take empty out. But It still not route to default or this project route maybe broken or something. Can it happen like this?

Answer (score 0):

The first empty route found in your Routes redirect to `/login`.

When you use `children` it implies that you parent component has it's own `router-outlet`.

I assume you LoginComponent is at the base of your routes so the `path` should also be at the root. Something like this:

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: AdminLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: MainComponent,
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'Main',
          status: true
        }
      },
      {
        path: 'userterminal',
        loadChildren: './userterminal/userterminal.module.ts#UserTerminalModule'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  }
];
```

With a structure like this when you use your redirect it will find the path since it is at the root.

Using and you can navigate to `main` from login success. 
Just remember if you are using children the parent component example `AdminLayoutComponent` must have a `router-outlet` in order to load it's children inside.